# javascript getDate issue

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if anyone could help me get the leading zero to show up when I do a getDate? Right now it's showing up as 8/3/2010 ... I would like it 08/03/2010.

Comment: see a format you want from http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to detect if the value of the day and month is less than 10 and add the zero yourself:

```
var today = new Date();
var day = today.getDate();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var year = today.getFullYear();

var formatted =
    (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day + "/"  +
    (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month + "/"  +
    year;

alert(formatted);
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/M8PKG/).  Note that you add one to the month as January = 0 rather than 1.

Answer (score 1):

I coded an example for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var d = new Date();

var curr_date = d.getDate();

var curr_month = d.getMonth();

var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

curr_month = curr_month + "";
if(curr_month.length == 1){
    curr_month = "0" + curr_month;  
}

curr_date = curr_date + "";
if(curr_date.length == 1){
    curr_date = "0" + curr_date;    
}

document.write(curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year);
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) is a nice blogpost on how to implement a dateformat function

if you are using mootools you cat use the Native/Date function

for jquery there is a dateformat plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need to either DIY or find a script.

The [link](http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format) provided by haim evgi is sufficient. After including the library, you can use it as followed:

```
var d = new Date;
alert(d.format('d/m/Y'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this lib: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format
Solved formatting issues for me on many levels ;)